# How do I configure uwsgi as a production WSGI server?

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord, flask

I have a flask app that I want to run using `uwsgi`. I am also managing the `uwsgi` with `supervisor`.
here is the my supervisor.conf file

```
[program:myapp]
command=/opt/python_envs/apps/bin/uwsgi --ini /opt/apps/myapp_wsgi.ini
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/program_myapp.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/program_myapp.error
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=5
user=root
environment=PATH='/opt/python_envs/apps/bin'
directory=/opt/apps
```

Here is the myapp_wsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /opt/apps/myapp
http = :8880
module = myapp:app
enable-threads = true
master = true
processes = 2
uid=root
gid=www-data
socket = myapp.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
need-app = true
die-on-term = true
logger = file:/opt/apps/myapp/logs/uwsgi.log
```

The problem is that when supervisor starts I see in `/var/log/supervisor/program_myapp.log`

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

I understand that this is Flask's development server's warning message.
How do I use production WSGI server Instead?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried The uWSGI HTTP/HTTPS router as well. Same result.